# NFC payments in store

Tags: store, nfc, tap-to-pay

I'm pretty sure I know the answer but asking for my partner. We've both got new contract sims & Lumia 640 each. We know we can pay for apps & games through our pay monthly contract. My partner wants to know if we can do similar to pay for items in store via NFC?

Comment: If you have two questions, please post them separately, otherwise tracking the answers, comments and votes can get a bit messy. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, got my partner to post for me & he decided to put them together! I'll break them up now!

Comment: I assume you mean a "physical" store - not the Windows Store?

Comment: Yea, like going in to buy groceries etc. I'm also having major issues paying for things via windows stor. Desperate to buy minecraft, and add funds to poker, but everytime I try it's saying it can't connect to the store.